# Inline Javascript Timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I use jQuery to insert html divs to notify the user. I need to make an inline javascript timer that closes the notification after a certain ammount of time. This is how the div looks:

[`FIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/simbyone/EmZND/)

Comment: what you really need?this is not understandable

Comment: [`.delay(x).fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) You should put relevant code in your question by the way rather than just linking to a demo.

Comment: Just a suggestion - you might want to stop/pause the auto close timer when you're hovering over the notify div :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i make a solution...

http://jsfiddle.net/Castrolol/EmZND/14/

when you add the tab mark to hide, you can put on a data-time attr the time what you want to hide...

the code...

```
addtab = setInterval( add_tab, 3000 );


function add_tab(){
var timeToHide = 6500;

var tab = $('<div class="rightnot-tab"><div class="rightnot-tab-image"><img src="http://movies.dosthana.com/sites/default/files/image-gallery/Bradley%20Cooper%20Stills.jpg" width="60" height="60"/></div><div class="rightnot-tab-text"><a href="#">Bradley Cooper</a> added you as a friend</div><div class="rightnot-tab-close"><img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/lynx/22x22/actions/dialog-close.png" width="22" height="22"/></div></div>');

$("#rightnot").hide().prepend(tab).fadeIn(500)

setTimeout(function(){
   removeTab(tab);

},timeToHide);



$('.rightnot-tab-close').click(function(){
    removeTab($(this).parent());    
    })

}

function removeTab( tab ) { //you can change the implementation
     $(tab).animate({ opacity: 0 }, function(){
        $(tab).slideUp(500, function(){
            $(tab).remove();
        });    
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Give an id to the prepended div (with a timestamp or something random).
2. Within the function add_tab you call a new function 'remove_tab' with the generated id as its parameter.
3. When remove_tab runs, it should remove the div with the id that was passed through the parameter.
4. Success

No need to install seperate plugins or whatever

Answer (score 0):

**you have to take help of jquery plugin**

Like http://flipclockjs.com/

**You have to download this JS add in your script**

```
clock.start(function() {
// this (optional) callback will fire each time the clock flips
});
to start timer

clock.stop(function() {
// this (optional) callback will fire after the clock stops
```

});
   to stop timer

```
clock.setTime(3600);
clock.setCountdown(true);
var time  = clock.getTime();
```

**In this way you can get your desired result**